# How do I create a custom Edit Contact form in Outlook 2016?

Tags: outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, outlook-2016

I'd like to be able to select a contact, and, either via right-click or a ribbon button, "Edit Advanced", which would take me to a form similar to the existing Edit Contact form but with some custom fields.

I'm thinking C# VSTO but I'm open to any solution that works.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm confused - if you go into form edit mode for an item that was created from a custom form, you will be editing that same custom form. If that's not what you mean please clarify

Comment: @ericlegault It's fine if I edit using the same form the item was created with. However, what I really want to do is edit existing contacts with this custom form. Essentially I'd like to use this to streamline populating my contacts' custom fields.

Comment: I see - I'll add an answer

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do is change the MessageClass property of existing contacts (IPM.Contact) to the value of your custom form (e.g. IPM.Contact.Foo).  So you will need to write a macro or add-in that will change this for all or selected items in any given folder.

There's a sample and tool available here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/201087/how-to-update-existing-items-in-an-outlook-folder-to-use-a-new-custom